# When packaging my kivy app for android the apk keeps crashing

Tags: python, android, crash, kivy, kivymd

So I've used buildozer for packaging my kivy app and I'm using it through Google Colab. It used to package fine before but for some reason it's stopped opening past the splash screen for the app. It works fine on windows so I think there's a compatibility issue somewhere.

It's not a Google Colab/buildozer bug as I tried some dummy code and that packaged fine and was running.

Note: I always rename the files to main.py and main.kv in Colab and also change the `return Builder.loaf_file` from design.kv to main.kv. Also some of the imports seem useless here but this is just from a section of the code so they're used later in the program. But if any of these might cause an error please let me know.

Edit: here are the requirements I used for Buildozer `python3,kivy==2.0.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow` I also changed the kivy version in the buildozer.spec file to 2.0.0 also

Thanks in advance

main.py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import sqlite3
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

class Home(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None

    def coming_soon_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                text = "Coming Soon!",
            )

        self.dialog.open()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('Design.kv')

MainApp().run()
```

design.kv:

```
#:import webbrowser webbrowser

WindowManager:

    Home:
        name: "home"

<MyTile@SmartTileWithLabel>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "210dp"


<Home>:
    name: 'home'

    MDFloatLayout:
        cols: 1
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            MDFloatLayout:
                cols: 2

                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Courses"
                        md_bg_color: 250/255, 205/255, 62/255, 1
                        specific_text_color: 255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1

                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"


                        MDGridLayout:
                            cols: 2
                            adaptive_height: True
                            padding: dp(4), dp(4)
                            spacing: dp(4)
                            size_hint: (1,1)

                            MyTile:
                                source: ""
                                size_hint: (0.5,0.25)
                                text: "[size=30]Test1[/size]\n"

                                on_press:
                                    app.coming_soon_dialog()

                            MyTile:
                                source: ""
                                size_hint: (0.5,0.25)
                                text: "[size=30]Test2[/size]\n"

                                on_press:
                                    app.coming_soon_dialog()

                            MyTile:
                                source: ""
                                size_hint: (0.5,0.25)
                                text: "[size=30]Test3[/size]\n"

                                on_press:
                                    app.coming_soon_dialog()

                            MyTile:
                                source: ""
                                size_hint: (0.5,0.25)
                                text: "[size=30]Test4[/size]\n"

                                on_press:
                                    app.coming_soon_dialog()

                            MyTile:
                                source: ""
                                size_hint: (0.5,0.25)
                                text: "[size=30]Test5[/size]"

                                on_press:
                                    app.coming_soon_dialog()

                            MyTile:
                                source: ""
                                size_hint: (0.5,0.25)
                                text: "[size=30]Test6[/size]"

                                on_press:
                                    app.coming_soon_dialog()
```

Comment: Note that the changes you have specified will result in `main.kv` getting loaded twice. That can cause problems and may or may not be your problem. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv).

Comment: @JohnAnderson I also tried making another apk without including the Builder.load_file line but that still ended up crashing so I don't think that's what's causing the issue. Also I did the same thing in a few prior apks too but they ran without issue. But I'll make sure to change that thanks.